# How to add missing dependecies to third-part library

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, dependencies

I try to use third-part jar library. Unfotunately it seems as it's missing some dependecies:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "thirdparty.android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr"`

Can I add it somehow to this jar?
By myself, I use that `android.support.v7.appcompat`, why the attached third-part library doesn't try to use that code and it looks for it in itself?

Do I understand it right?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, right click on your app module > Open Module Setting > select your app module > Dependencies > try remove "com.android.support:appcompat-v7" and click ok, after removing the dependency, simply synchronize the whole project will be done

Comment: It still doesn't work - I still get errors about missing classes in third-party library.

Comment: do you mind providing me your 3rd party jar? Since I am not sure it is the library class missing problem or your import flow's problem

Comment: @S.W. Thank you, but I'm affraid I'm not allowed to share that library.
What do you mean by "import flow's problem"?

Comment: It means fail to import the dependency to be implemented in the project